# TypeScript - specify type while object destructuring with alias

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, alias, destructuring

I'm refactoring an NodeJS app to TypeScript. And I was making always object destructuring and also for the code block below I'm making and alias while object destructuring as you see. And how can I specify type here?

```
const {length: isRegistered} = await User.countDocuments({email: emailTo});
```

Comment: `const { length: isRegistered }: { length: number } = await User.countDocuments({email: emailTo});`

Answer (score 2):

I would favour typing the return type of `User.countDocuments({email: emailTo})`, which should be similar to `Promise<{ length: number, ... }>`.
That way, TypeScript will infer the type of the destructed properties.

Another way is to be more explicit by typing `const {length: isRegistered} : {length: number}`.

Comment: i got an error that: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ length: number; }'.ts(2322)
https://imgur.com/hYGm47k

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ahmetbcakici/dabec6c23b69c68635b406e34d82f89b

Comment: How is `countDocuments` typed?

Comment: it is number, i already also tried to make it "any" type though error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215927/discussion-between-ahmetbcakici-and-morkadosh).